# Is there a way to automatically reset an embedded form once submitted?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a Cognito form embedded in a webpage that I repeatedly fill and submit.

To populate a new instance, I always need to refresh the webpage after submitting the previous form. I want to eliminate the need to "refresh."

Is there a way to automatically reset an embedded form once it is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer at Cognito Forms.

No, [customization options for confirmation pages](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/14/building-forms/create-customized-confirmation-pages) do not include a way to refresh a form followimg submission.

You can however achieve something similar by:

1. Switching to the   **Redirect** option in the **Confirmation** dialog
2. Setting the **Redirect URL** to the webpage where you embedded the form.

Redirecting to the same webpage after submission has the same effect as you are achieving refreshing manually.

#### Warnings

1. [AMP embedding](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/183/style-publish/amp-embedding) does not support the **Redirect** option.
2. Replacing the confirmation **Message** (page) with a **Redirect** could be confusing to users.

Answer (score -1):

This may be an old topic, but I had the same question and found a workaround for anyone else who comes along. When embedded, there is a way to do this. I can't speak to whether this solution works with the iframe or AMP, but it definitely works with the seamless embed.

1. Look [here](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/380/style-publish/seamless-embedding) for more info about prefilling a seamless embedded cognito form, because that's what this relies on.
2. In your form, add a hidden field titled something like "EmbedURL". Go to the Workflow settings, under the Submit button (or whatever button you want), select to Redirect upon submission, and insert the "EmbedURL" field into the blank.
3. In your webpage's code, prefill the "EmbedURL" field to be window.location.href. The prefill code goes beneath your seamless embed code, and should look something like this:

> <script>
> Cognito.prefill({"EmbedURL":window.location.href});
>
> </script>

Your webpage will be running this javascript, and window.location.href is the URL to your current page. So this should work anywhere. So what ends up happening is the web page passes this value into a field in the cognito form, which then uses that field to redirect to after submission.

I would certainly love to see this function built into Cognito Forms. This method only works for embeds, and maybe even only the seamless embed. Simply having a "Refresh" option next to the "Redirect" and "Message" options would be simple enough to implement and, I think, widely used.

Comment: Basically, the [same answer @Nicholas provided](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/109331/1) albeit yours adds additional (unnecessary?) steps.